# IIS 7.5 Error on Restful WCF 4.0

Tags: wcf, web-config, c#-4.0

I've been trying to do a simple restful wcf service that will return JSON. Its working if i will run it in the development server. However if I deploy it on IIS 7.5, i will have this error when i accessed it using *http://localhost:70*

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Config Error The configuration section
>   'standardEndpoints' cannot be read
>   because it is missing a section
>   declaration

Here is my configuration file: This is the default file generated by the VS2010.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="LocationService" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Im new to WCF specially on .net 4.0 and IIS 7.5.

Can anybody help? Or anybody has experienced the same and has fixed already?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you definitely have the IIS application pool for your site configured to run with ASP .NET 4.0?

Right click your Virtual Directory in IIS Manager > Manage Application > Advanced Settings > read the app pool name.

Then go to Application Pools, find that name and make sure the .NET Framework column says v4.0.

Comment: thanks for this man, i have checked and found out that my application creates its own application pool that uses asp.net 2.0 instead of 4.0. Now its working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on a w2008 x64 with the app pool running .net 4.0; after installing SP2 the issue disappeared

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be seen on Windows Server 2008 without service pack 2 installed. To fix the problem install Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2.

Taken from [Ram Poornalingam's WebLog entry from the 26th October 2009](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2009/10/26/net-4-0-beta1-beta2-web-application-configuration-section-missing-declaration-error.aspx):

> If you encounter the following error in your web application (things hosted in IIS) “The configuration section  cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"
>
> examples
>
> “The configuration section 'standardEndpoints' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration”
>
> “The configuration section ‘tracking’ cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration”
>
> then you need to install either SP2 of Vista/Win2k8 or the hotfix mentioned in KB article 958854.

Comment: This was exactly the issue we faced after upgrading some old x86 app servers from IIS 6 (2003) to IIS 7 (2008 SP2). Thanks for sharing the fix!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to ask a question that may seem obvious to some, but it might help others (mainly me) if you could clarify the last step:

Then go to Application Pools...

Where do I find Application Pools ?

If you can't tell I am used to working for big companies where someone else did that for me and now I am playing developer and IT director.

Thanks

Ok, after 10 seconds of research (I opened my eyes) and looked right above Sites in IIS Manager

[image]